# Unable to send image to ffmpeg stdin from QProcess

Tags: python, windows, ffmpeg, pyqt5

It not writing png file. I want to save central widget to png file. I have 2 files, one is main file and second one is ui file. Link has ui file.

Getting error code:

> QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from green import Ui_MainWindow
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)

    self.setupUi(self)
    self.widger_screen()

def widger_screen(self):

    self.process = QtCore.QProcess(app)
    self.process.setProcessChannelMode(self.process.ForwardedChannels)
    self.process.setOpenMode(self.process.WriteOnly)
    self.process.start('ffmpeg',
                       ['-y',
                        '-analyzeduration', '1000',
                        '-vcodec', 'png', '-i', '-',
                        '-vcodec', 'mpeg4',
                        '-qscale', '5', '-r', '24', 'video.avi',
                        "-loglevel", "debug"])
    for i in range(100):
        QWidget.grab(self.centralwidget).save(self.process, "PNG")

if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

green.ui
https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ugorifokiq.py

Answer (score 0):

There are different problems with your code.

First of all, you have to specify the *format* of the image, so the correct syntax is:

```
QWidget.grab(self.centralwidget).save(process, "PNG")
```

In fact, in your case `save()` would have returned `False`, while with the correct format now returns `True`.

Also, you'll need a minimum amount of frames to ensure that ffmpeg has enough data to actually start to processs. This amount is expressed in the `analyzeduration` value, and defaults to 5000000 microseconds (5 seconds). Since you're only grabbing 100 frames (less than 4 seconds) that wouldn't be enough, so either increase the number of recorded frames, or add the `analyzeduration` option near the *beginning* of the options, using a lower value (but still higher than 0).

```
    self.process.start('ffmpeg',
              ['-y', 
              '-analyzeduration', '100', 
              '-vcodec', 'png', '-i', '-', 
              '-vcodec', 'mpeg4', 
              '-qscale', '5', '-r', '24', 'video.avi',
               "-loglevel", "debug"])
```

Another issue (after your editing) is that you mistyped the `loglevel` option. This is clear from the output when running the program from the prompt/shell:

```
Unrecognized option 'loglevel2'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

While you won't get an error/exception, the result is that the ffmpeg process exits, making it impossible to write the output file.

---

Finally, some considerations:

1. starting a grab operation while the widget is still in the **init** function could result in incoherent resizing, as some widgets might require time to "polish" themselves (usually at least one event loop cycle *after* **init** returns, like item views).
2. grabbing a whole widget "screenshot" could take a *lot* of time; I don't have a powerful computer (it's a ~2012 Intel i5, 4 core @ 3.4GHz) and each grab takes more than 120ms on Linux on a very light window system (your window size is even bigger than a standard full HD video): the whole process takes about 12 seconds until the grabbing process finishes and the window is finally shown (that's due to the fact that the grabbing is done *before* `show()` can be called); I'm pretty sure that there could be some good solution to *queue* the grabbed pixmap to the `stdout` with threading, but you'd have to be careful about it as QPixmap objects are not thread safe; if you want to do that, you'd better create a new separate question;
3. the grabbed widget could change its size (possibly due to user interaction) and as soon as it happens, the output video will be resized; if the output format supports resizing that wouldn't a big issue, but you could get an inconsistent behavior, expecially when trying to transcoding to other formats that don't support video resizing;

Comment: I think I did something wrong because it still doesn't work

Comment: Does `save()` return True? Do you see some output from ffmpeg besides the start messages? (please, do not add an answer if it only says that you still have the issue, comments are for this)

Comment: save() return True yes. I think I can't see. 
And the program crashes in the beginning

Comment: Can you edit your question including a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Yes I can. since i'm new then i have to look how to do it

Comment: Read the link I posted in my previous comment, ensure to create a *minimal* example that people can easily copy, paste, run and understand.

Comment: @Go0od I've updated my answer. For future reference, if you apply important changes to your questions after clarification requests, ensure that the people commenting both questions and answers get a notification through a new comment.

Comment: I changed loglevel2 to loglevel. But still not writing png file. I got error: QWindowsPipeWriter::write failed. (The handle is invalid.)

Comment: That seems a window specific error regarding the piping between the two processes, but I don't use Windows and can't help you with that. Update your question (and the title, as it's *not* descriptive: questions starting with "why does this code not work?" are often ignored), include the new error and specify all versions of PyQt, Python, Windows and ffmpeg you're using.

Comment: You don't need to specify the whole framework in the title (I already updated your title, btw), you need to specify the **versions** of PyQt, Python, Windows and ffmpeg in the question.